# In-house distribution - ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I have confuse about in-house distribution and ad-hoc distribution.

1. Does in-house and ad-hoc distribution application need to get apple review team to review?
2. What is different between in-house distribution and ad-hoc distribution?
3. Any example/guide line for create in-house application certificate and process for distribution?
4. Did in-house distribution need to collect user UDID to configure?
5. If I started distribute "A" application using in-house / ad-hoc distribution, can I distribute the "A" application to App store later?

Answer (score 3):

1. No they do not.
2. With the in-house distribute you are allowed to install the app on any iOS device that is used by employees of the company without the device's UDID. The Ad-Hoc is for testing app on selected number of devices(100 unique device per account per year).
3. Yes, see Apple  [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html)
4. No, in-houe distributed app do not have any UDID restrictions.
5. YES, but you will need to enter the AppStore developer program and not the Enterprise one used for the in-house distribution.

Comment: For the answer 2, that means I can distribute to the other IOS device which is not device of company employees also?

Comment: @user831098 - yes but need to be enrolled in the Enterprise Program

Comment: Yes you can give everyone the app, but you will be breaking the agreement with Apple, which states that you can only distribute the app with company employees. If you do distribute with other user, Apple could/will discontinue you Apple Developers account.

Answer (score 0):

**Ad Hoc Distribution Authorizes a Limited Set of Devices to Run Your App**

iOS developers enrolled in the Standard Program can also distribute an app outside of the App Store on up to 100 different devices for testing purposes only. To use ad hoc distribution, create an archive of your app, or have a teammate send you an iOS App Store Package (.ipa) of the archived app.

You distribute your app by providing the .ipa file for users to install on their devices. Because you select a valid ad hoc provisioning profile to archive the app, users don’t need to install the profile on their device, only the .ipa file. Users can use iTunes to install the app on their devices. If users want to use Xcode to install the app on their device, share the archive as an .xcarchive file package.

**In-House Distribution Allows Companies to Distribute Apps Internally**
iOS developers enrolled in the Enterprise Program can distribute in-house without identifying individual devices or using the App Store. To distribute your app in-house, create an archive of your app, or have a teammate send you an archived app. Distribute your internal app using your company’s authorized software distribution mechanism. Because the app file can be installed on any iOS device, make sure you protect the distribution of this file. Members of your company can use iTunes, iPhone Configuration Utility, or Xcode to install the app on their devices.